# Harden / Lock down SMB share

Tags: network, hardening

We have to use an embedded SMB server to transfer medical records to and from patients' phones.

The medical records are AES-encrypted on the phones, in transit and on the embedded device. But then... the embedded device only supports transferring the unencrypted files over SMB to/from a workstation. D'oh!

And the embedded SMB server uses a default user name and password which is publicly available and *cannot be changed*. D'oh!?

**So the question is: How do you lock down that SMB share?**
How do you prevent an attacker who somehow gets access to our network from sucking up all the data from the SMB share and uploading it to his own server on the internet? Or from sending malicious files to customers' phones by depositing them in the patient's folder on the SMB share?

- The SMB share needs to be accessed from two workstations with static IPs.
- We can't do anything to the SMB server. No SSH, web UI, nothing.
- We **must** use this device. Please don't tell me that we shouldn't.

**My idea:**
Use a port on our firewall just for the SMB server and restrict connections to that firewall interface to the IP and MAC addresses of the two workstations. However, I believe that a device configured to use the IP of one of the workstations and with MAC spoofing could still access the SMB share. Is that correct?

Comment: You are correct, spoofing or mitm will work. Do you have control over the clients?